# What's a good notation for showing MVC interactions?

Tags: design, design-patterns, uml, diagrams, bpmn

I'm developing various websites and functionality to cater to various different use-cases up in Django.

Is there a good notation for showing what behaviour is at each stage, e.g., swimlanes.

I use BPMN 2 notation for everything, but feel that I am overusing this, and probably abusing the notation :P

Example:

[image: BPMN 2.0 diagram]

Please recommend a suitable **notation for showing the interactions between model, view and controller, as well as some of the inner business-logic in each stage**.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagrams look clean and accurate. A good diagram type for

> for showing the interactions between model, view and controller

would be a [uml sequence diagram](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_interaction_diagram.htm). For your

> inner business-logic in each stage

i recommend [uml statechart diagrams](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_statechart_diagram.htm).

Are you generating code from them or is it just a documentation? If you just document it feels like overuse, cause you have to update always the code and the diagrams. I would only use it where the code is to complex (if this isn't a smell and any better design exists).

But if you cultivate these diagrams for customers, then they are great (if your customers understand them ;) )!

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I'm making these diagrams so that developers better understand the system, and so that they can troubleshoot logic errors at the high-level of a diagram. Sequence diagram isn't what I'm looking for... :\